# Will out of bag error always be 100% for classes of size 1 using random forests

Tags: random-forest, ensemble-learning, data-preprocessing

My understanding is that given a sample data point $x_i$ the OOB prediction for this point will be calculated using only trees in the ensemble that do not contain $x_i$ in their bootstrap sample. Thus if $x_i$ is the only value in a given class the trees used for generating an OOB prediction for $x_i$ will be grown using no samples from the same class, thus will always incorrectly classify $x_i$. is this correct? If so, whats the best way to deal with classes containing only one value, simply remove them?

Comment: "If so, whats the best way to deal with classes containing only one value, simply remove them?" Collect more data!

Comment: You have performed the very common crime against statistics of "throwing away otherwise good data"!  You can't do that and be honest.  You do not get to throw away data that you do not like.  … so why could you not retain a point for your analysis?  If you can prove it is bad using expertise in the field showing for example a bad sensor, or lack of calibration.  Get a good reason or you must keep the sample!  You wouldn't kill the last dinosaur or last dragon so don't kill the only data point of its species. the standard deviation of a size one sample is zero.  You have to live with that.